# Error while converting string using ast.literal_eval

Tags: python

I am running into the error below. I can't figure out what's wrong in `clonedRadardetails`. Any guidance will be helpful.

```
import ast
clonedRadardetails = {'clonedRadar': u'42719619', 'clonedStatus': 'PASS', 'clonedRadarFinalStatus': 'PASS', 'updatedFailedReason': 'N/A', 'clonedRadarFinalStatusReason': 'N/A', 'updateStatus': 'PASS', 'clonedStatusfailReason': 'N/A'}
v = ast.literal_eval(clonedRadardetails)
```

Error:

```
 File "astliteral.py", line 3, in <module>
    v = ast.literal_eval(clonedRadardetails)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Comment: That is not a string. Why are you trying to `literal_eval` it?

Comment: `literal_eval` is intended for evaluating *strings* that have literals defined in them, basically bits of code, literal declarations. Why are you trying to eval an entire dictionary? What are you hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for ast.literal_eval():

Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None